# Close virtual keybord automatically in .net

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on windows form application, while clicking textbox I want to enable virtual keyboard so I wrote the following code in my `TxtName_GotFocus` event

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe");
    //SetFocus to your TextBox here
    textBox1.Focus();
}
```

but I want to close this virtual keyboard in the `TxtName_LostFocus`
so how I can write the code?

Comment: This looks like `vb.net` not `c#`.

Comment: `Process.Start` returns a [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) object. Don't throw that away.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to the LostFocus event of the textbox:

```
Process keyboardProcess;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.keyboardProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe");
    //SetFocus to your TextBox here
    textBox1.Focus();
}

private void textbox1_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.keyboardProcess.Kill();
}
```

Comment: showing error:Cannot process request because the process has exited.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe");
    //SetFocus to your TextBox here
    textBox1.Focus();
}

private void textbox1_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("osk");
    if (procs.Length != 0)
        procs[0].Kill();
}
```

Comment: I am not OP, but idea was interesting, so I've tested it and confirmed. But I am unable to *mark* anything, only upvote.